# ECommerce website having issues with Add or removing items from cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an ecommerce website, it uses WooCommerce plugin and Elementor as theme. The issue happens when a customer adds more than one of the same items, for example when I add 3 of the shirts to the cart, I click the minus and the plus to add or remove, but it stays the same, nothing adds or subtracts. How could I solve the problem?

I tried deactivating the WooCommerce plugin and changing themes.

Comment: have you checked that there is no conflict between versions? (Your theme version is compatible with WC version). It seems like a js or jq conflict. can you share the code to make some tests?

Comment: It's a WordPress site.  There is no conflict.

Comment: yeah, i know, WC uses WP to function. can you share the code to make tests?.

Comment: Check to make sure the products in your plugin aren't restricted to only permitting users to buy 1 of each item.